# How can I open a discussion with another member in their post?

Tags: support

How can I open a discussion with another member in their post, since we both experience the same car problem?

I used the "answer" button, and got my message suspended by the moderator as illegal operation.

Please explain to me the rules over here.

Comment: "Here" as compared to where? Try this for a start: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tour. Then you could consider posting this on Meta or in the PitStop.

Answer (score 3):

Just ask a new question and link it back to the original question. If it is the same exact question and it hasn't received an answer yet, I doubt you're going to get an answer to a separate question, and it will most likely get closed as a duplicate.